# How to use FFTW with cmake on windows?

Tags: build, cmake, fftw

I am building my project for Visual Studio with CMake. I used this lines in my CMakeList.txt to include FFTW3.

```
find_library(FFTW_LIBRARY
     NAMES fftw3 fftw)
set(FFTW_LIBRARIES "${FFTW_LIBRARY}")
```

I got this error from CMake:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
FFTW_LIBRARY
    linked by target "windows_SHT" in directory C:/...
```

I think I did not install fftw properly. I got .dll .lib and .h files in a folder but I don't know how to explain to CMake where is the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify additional paths for find_library to use.

See: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:find_library

You will need to include the path to your custom FFTW installation.

A similar technique will need to be used when you use find_file to locate the headers

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:find_file